# How to customize display format in jquery jtable

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I have a status data field in my database and I need this data on my jquery jtable to be displayed in different format like, if the data is 1 display a red button and if data is 0 display a green button. How can I do this in jquery jtable?

Comment: SO does not work like that,you need to post the sample code which you have tried so far. refer this page foe more information. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
publish: {
                    title: '',
                    width: '0.65%',
                    list: true,
                    sorting:false,
                    type: 'radiobutton',
                    options: { '1': 'Publish', '0': 'Unpublish' },
                    display: function (data) {
                        //alert(data.record.publish);
                        if(data.record.publish == '1'){
                            return '<button id="un" style = "width:90px; max-width:90px; text-align:center;" class="btn btn-danger" title="Unpublish Post" type="button" onclick="changeStatus('+data.record.OID+');">Unpublish</button>';
                        }
                        else {
                            return '<button id="pub" style= "max-width:90px; width:90px; text-align:center;" class="btn btn-success" title="Publish Post" type="button" onclick="changeStatus('+data.record.OID+');">Publish</button>';
                        }
                    }
      }
```